# ResourceAuthorizationManager: can it inspect the parameters?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I'm trying to use a Thinktecture ResourceAuthorizationManager to secure an API endpoint like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword(string userName,  string newPassword )
```

I want to allow users to change their own passwords or allow administrators to change anyone else's password.

Can the ResourceAuthorizationManager inspect the arguments passed into the method it protects?  If not, is that a bad idea for reasons I cannot see?